# What is the best way of forwarding a link to the same link but on a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, server, url-rewriting, hosting

Say I wanted to forward links from the main domain to the subdomain, what would be the best way of doing it? I understand this probably makes 0 sense, so please see below.

- End link: `sub.example.com/page`
- Forwarding link: `example.com/page`

I know how to do individual pages, but I can't for the life of me think of any way of doing it so that it is automatic. I feel like the .HTACCESS is the best route, but again, I am at a loss of how this would be done.

Running on shared, Linux based hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you need is a single, simple RewriteRule to implement an external redirection. You will find tons of existing and working examples for that here on SO or in any tutorial about request rewriting.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?page https://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

For this to work the apache rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server and rewriting needs to be enabled to the requested location, obviously.

It is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only to change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once you are satisfied with the implementation. That prevents nasty caching issues for your users.

In general you should prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you have no access to that you certainly can use a *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess"), but that comes with a few disadvantages. Also their interpretation needs to be enabled for the requested location first using the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. I will give it a go. Cheers